# Laravel 5 - Laracast Easy Auth - Saving an article

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was following a tutorial on laracast about easy auth ([Easy Auth](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/15?autoplay=true)), but there were some gaps on the video, i had to declare

```
 use Auth;
```

to be able to get the current user, however, when i save the article i get this error

```
FatalErrorException in ArticleController.php line 42:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save()
```

where the corresponding code in my ArticleController is

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article = new Article($request->all());

    Auth::user()->articles->save($article);

    return redirect('blog');
}
```

My Article model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Article extends Model {

protected $fillable = [
'title',
'body',
'published_at',
'user_id'
];

protected $dates = ['published_at'];

public function scopePublished ($query)
{
    $query->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now());

}

public function scopeUnpublished ($query)
{
    $query->where('published_at', '>', Carbon::now());

}

public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this-> belongsTo('App\User');
}

}
```

My User model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,     CanResetPasswordContract {

use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

public function articles()
{
    return $this-> hasMany('App\Article');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);
```

store action

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article = new Article($request->all());
    Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);
    return redirect('blog');
}
```